# Why do I need double call to setPageFromHash() method?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I would like to know why I need double call to `setPageFromHash()` method?
I tried to see also on debugger, and the call inside the `addeventlistener` takes me to the last line - the call to `setPageFromHash`. 
Is it not enough to call the method? 
I was thinking that the call inside `addEventListener` will take the debugger to the function call on line 12.

```
var main = document.querySelector('main');

function showPage(name) {   var html = document.getElementById(`t-${name}`).innerHTML;   main.innerHTML = html;   }

window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {   setPageFromHash(); });

function setPageFromHash() {   
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
     if (hash === 'about') {
    showPage('about');   } 
    else {
    showPage('home');   
 } 
}

setPageFromHash();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call a function inside addEventListener arguments. You can just pass the name of a function which you want to call on the event:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', setPageFromHash);
```

Comment: ok, but  i saw this example and i still want to know what is the answer to my question